# XPath drops contents of td column on an HTML page for screen scraping

Tags: c#, xpath, selectnodes

Below you find an excerpt of code used to screen scrape an economic calendar.
The HTML page that it parses using XPath includes this row as the first rown
in a table. (Only pasted this row instead of the entire HTML page.)

```
<tr class="calendar_row newday singleevent" data-eventid="42064"> <td class="date"><div class="date">Sun<div>Dec 23</div></div></td> <td class="time">All Day</td> <td class="currency">JPY</td> <td class="impact"> <div title="Non-Economic" class="holiday"></div> </td> <td class="event"><div>Bank Holiday</div></td> <td class="detail"><a class="calendar_detail level1" data-level="1"></a></td> <td class="actual"> </td> <td class="forecast"></td> <td class="previous"></td> <td class="graph"></td> </tr>
```

This code that selects the first tr row using XPath:

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(new StringReader(html));
var rows = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[@class=\"calendar_row\"]");
var rowHtml = rows[0].InnerHtml;
```

The problem is that rowHtml returns this:

```
<td class="date"></td> <td class="time">All Day</td> <td class="currency">EUR</td> <td class="impact">  <div title="Non-Economic" class="holiday"></div>  </td> <td class="event"> <div>French Bank Holiday</div> </td> <td class="detail"><a class="calendar_detail level2" data-level="2"></a></td> <td class="actual"> </td> <td class="forecast"></td> <td class="previous"></td> <td class="graph"></td>
```

Now you can see that the contents of the td column for the date vanished! Why?

I've experimented many things and stumped as to why it drops the contents of that column.
The other columns have content that it keeps. So what's wrong with the date column?

Is there some kind of setting or property somewhere to cause or prevent dropping contents?

Even if you haven't got a clue what's wrong but have some suggestions of a way to investigate it more.

Comment: You are probably getting different row than one you want... Try making Html much simple first so it have just on row you expect to match...

Comment: @Alexei You're right. I assumed the rows came back in the same order as the HTML. Can they be in random order?

Comment: @Alexei  The row that I'm getting has this <tr class="calendar_row" which is an exact match for the selector of on calendar_row. But the first two skipped rows look like this: <tr class="calendar_row newday singleevent"   And also <tr class="calendar_row newday alt"  I wonder how to get those rows included?

Comment: @Wayne Nodes should be returned in document order.

Comment: @Alexei Yes. The problem was my selector was excluding certain rows. The answer to the solution is below. Thanks!

Comment: @Lego Thanks that it's resolved now since the problem was some rows getting excluded by the selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @AlexeiLevenkov mentioned, you must be selecting a different row than what you want.  You've pruned too much of essential problem away in an effort to simplify, but it's still clear what's wrong...

Consider that your input document might basically look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table>
  <tr class="calendar_row" data-eventid="12345">
    <td>This IS NOT the tr you're looking for</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="calendar_row newday singleevent" data-eventid="42064">
    <td>This IS the tr you're looking for</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The test `@class="calendar_row"` won't match against the `tr` you show, but it will match against the first row.

You could change your test to be `contains(@class,'calendar_row')` instead, but that would match both rows.  You're going to have to identify some content or attribute that's unique to the row you desire.  Perhaps the `@data-eventid` attribute would work -- can't tell without seeing your whole input file.

Comment: Your answer is spot on. I actually need ALL the rows so you're answer is perfect. Actually already found this myself but will mark yours the correct answer.